# How to invalidate timer while changing tab in tab bar

Tags: iphone, ios

When I am moving from one tab to another in the timer continues to run.
But I want to stop that timer.

So if anyone knows then please tell me which method i need to call while moving from one tab to another.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for the help but i don't get the solution.

Comment: See. I pointed you to the closest possible location of Apple's grandiose documentation where I could. If you don't know what to do with that, you should be probably trying to develop a bit more of algorithmical thought, ability to extract useful/relevant information from the documentation as well as some common sense. It is as simple as setting the delegate of the `UITabBarController` and implementing the `- tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop timer process like this,

```
if(self.TimeOfActiveUser) 
{
    [self.TimeOfActiveUser invalidate];
    self.TimeOfActiveUser = nil;
}
```

**Edit**
You can put this method when you pushing another method For Example: if you using Timer for Reload Data of TableView every 6 second then you can push particular row by selecting then you can put this two line of code in

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {

[self.TimeOfActiveUser invalidate];
self.TimeOfActiveUser = nil;


    objScore = [[CntrScore alloc]initWithNibName:@"CntrScore" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objScore animated:YES];

  }
```

**AND**

if your app Tab based you put timer stop code in `viewWillDisappear`

```
 -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     if(self.TimeOfActiveUser) 
     {
     [self.TimeOfActiveUser invalidate];
     self.TimeOfActiveUser = nil;
     }


 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but while moving from tab in which method I have to write this code.?

Comment: @Dilip, Check the updated answer. You can write this in `viewWillDisapper` method of current view.

Comment: But viewWillDisapper method of current view is not called while I move to another tab.

Comment: we giving you logic of code and line of code @Dilip but not implement bcz we can not know which type of project its depent on your code or logic..

Answer (score 1):

simplest answer is

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    //here
}
```

when ever you will click on tab, this function will be called and everything written in this function will be executed

Answer (score 0):

Check the tab bar index and write the code which is given below:

```
[yourtimername invalidate];
```

Comment: Please can you specify how to check tab bar index?